# Show notification when selecting country x when adding address in Prestashop 1.7

Tags: drop-down-menu, prestashop, alert, prestashop-1.7

I'm using Prestashop 1.7.6.8. When adding an address for members or those who want to place an order without being a member, for example, I want to show a warning on the screen if they choose Germany. Something like an information note. How can I do that? I'm new to Prestashop. Which file do I need to make changes? Thanks.

Comment: you should edit address controller and address template files, to be more clear, can you share a screenshot?

Comment: best thing would be to code a little module with a "hooked" js in website header to trigger an action based on address country input change. i suggest you to read here to have a better idea of the prestashop hook concept => https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/hooks/